# Zend Framework 2 + Doctrine ODM, "The Class was not found in the chain configured namespaces" error?

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine-odm, odm

When setting up ZF2 + ODM, I'm getting the following error:

```
The class 'Application\Document\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces
```

The current setup is as the following:

ZF2 stable, installed doctrine ODM via composer.phar with content of composer.json

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.0.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-mongo-odm-module": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

modules loaded

```
'modules' => array(
    'Application',
    'DoctrineModule',
    'DoctrineMongoODMModule',
),
```

hydrator and proxy dirs are created

```
$ ls -l data/DoctrineMongoODMModule/
total 0
drwxrwxrwx  2 wisu  staff  68 Sep 12 08:34 Hydrators
drwxrwxrwx  2 wisu  staff  68 Sep 12 08:35 Proxy
```

the odm config looks like

```
'driver' => array(
    'odm_default' => array(
        'drivers' => array(
            'Application\Document' => 'aplikasi'
        )
    ),
    'aplikasi' => array(
        'class' => 'Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
        'cache' => 'array',
        'paths' => array(
            'module/Application/src/Application/Document'
        )
    )
),
```

I'm trying to use the following mapping

```
<?php

namespace Application\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;

/** @ODM\Document(collection="user") */
class User
{
    /** @ODM\Id */
    private $id;

    /** @ODM\Field(type="string") */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @return the $id
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the $name
     */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param field_type $id
     */
    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @param field_type $name
     */
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

}
```

but calling it via

```
<?php

namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Application\Document\User;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

        $dm = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.documentmanager.odm_default');

        $user = new User();
        $user->setName("Gembul");

        $dm->persist($user);
        $dm->flush();

        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Any pointers?

Comment: I don't think the provided answer is correct. Does anybody else have any thoughts on what the issue might be?

Answer (score 3):

Real solution is not adding module.doctrine-mongo-odm.local.php into autoload directory, this lines worked for me as configuration

```
    'driver' => array(          
        'ODM_Driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../../module/Application/src/Application/Doctrine/Document')
        ),
        'odm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                'Application\Doctrine\Document' => 'ODM_Driver'
            )
        ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 3):

This installation works fine with the current versions:
[ZF2, MongoDB, and Doctrine installation](http://blog.redphoenixsoftware.com/zf2-mongodb-doctrine-installation/)

Copy the odm’s default config file to our config directory. You will then need to modify the module.doctrine-mongo-odm.local.php as to your sever specifications. This is the configuration file where you set your server hosts, ports, username, and passwords. For example purposes we will assume everything is running on the same local machine and not make any modifications.

This is a Application **module.config.php** that will work for a hybrid solution ORM / ODM:

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        'orm_driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
        ),
        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => 'orm_driver'
            )
        ),
        'odm_driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',          
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Document')
        ),
        'odm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ . '\Document' => 'odm_driver'
            )
        )                   
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem...

Config file module.doctrine-mongo-odm.local.php was not under autoload directory...

Comment: Are you sure that was actually the solution? I've got the same problem using DoctrineORMModule. I've tried putting the doctrine config array at a global level as well as having it called from the module level and I always get the same error.